# Complex SQL Query with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database with:

```
[business] must have a [location]
[location] may have many [business]
[location] may have many [postcode]
[postcode] may be for many [location]
[postcode] must have a [state]
```

I want a query to return the top 10 locations for each state in terms of the business count.

To make more sense, it may come out:

```
Western Australia
  - perth
  - bunbury
  - etc. up to 10
```

(i.e. perth has the most businesses listed in Western Australia)

```
Victoria
  - melbourne
  - st kilda
  - etc. up to 10
```

Etc.

I was hoping to achieve this without using UNION. I haven't done complex SQL for a while and it's hurting my head.

I am using MySQL.

A similar way to put this would be if you had categories, products and orders and wanted the the top ten products in terms of order count for each category.

Comment: You're going to need to include your table definitions if you want people to help you craft a MySQL query

Comment: If you use the categories, products and orders example at the end you could imagine a standard table definition. It's just as much a conceptual question about how to achieve this. I'm happy to write the query I just have no idea how to structure it without using union.

Comment: Tagged with `greatest-n-per-group` to guide you to similar questions -- I saw someone else do this (and took the exact comment! :-). Anyway, this would done with SQL Server with `ROW_NUMBER(...PARTITION ON...)` so it's a matter of finding a (nice) MySQL equivalent, if it exits.

Comment: This question perked my interest, so I started looking at it ... best explanation/example I could find was http://explainextended.com/2009/03/05/row-sampling/. It uses some messy 'side-effecting' variables but the article states it runs in `Omega(n)` so it should be fine. This is similar as cyberkiwi proposed below.

Answer (score 1):

This query should work.

```
select * from (
    select a.state, a.location_id, C,
        @n:=case when @s=a.state then @n+1 else 1 end counter,
        @s:=a.state
    from (select @s:=null) b, (
        select pc.state, b.location_id, COUNT(b.location_id) C
        from postcode pc
        inner join location_postcode lp on lp.postcode_id=pc.id
        inner join business b on b.location_id=lp.location_id
        group by pc.state, b.location_id
        order by pc.state, C desc
    ) a
) c
where counter <= 10
```

I used field names that should be easy to follow, assuming these tables exist with stated relationships:

```
business M-1 location
location M-M postcode
    (expands to) => location 1-M location_postcode M-1 postcode
postcode M-1 state
```

The query has beentested with this data:

```
create table business (location_id int);
insert into business select floor(rand()*10);
insert into business select floor(rand()*10) from business;
insert into business select floor(rand()*10) from business;
insert into business select floor(rand()*10) from business;
insert into business select floor(rand()*10) from business;
insert into business select floor(rand()*10) from business;
insert into business select floor(rand()*10) from business;
insert into business select floor(rand()*10) from business;
insert into business select floor(rand()*10) from business;
insert into business select floor(rand()*10) from business;
create table location_postcode (location_id int, postcode_id int);
insert into location_postcode select 1,1;
insert into location_postcode select 2,1;
insert into location_postcode select 3,1;
insert into location_postcode select 4,2;
insert into location_postcode select 5,1;
insert into location_postcode select 5,2;
insert into location_postcode select 6,1;
insert into location_postcode select 6,3;
insert into location_postcode select 7,1;
insert into location_postcode select 7,4;
insert into location_postcode select 8,5;
insert into location_postcode select 9,6;
insert into location_postcode select 10,7;
create table postcode (id int, state int);
insert into postcode select 1,1;
insert into postcode select 2,2;
insert into postcode select 3,3;
insert into postcode select 4,4;
insert into postcode select 5,4;
insert into postcode select 6,5;
insert into postcode select 7,5;
```

Which doesn't quite create enough records for a "top 10" from each, but you will see how the COUNTER column is ranking correctly.  To see it working against this small data set, first leave this filter in there

```
where counter <= 10
```

to check the COUNTER column, then reduce it to something like 2 or 3, to show only the top 2 or 3 per state.